# why the program works on visual studio code but doesn't work on pythonanywhere?

Tags: pythonanywhere

i tried to run this program on pythonanywhere but it doesn't work, why?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
wbe = webdriver.Chrome('/home/Picen22/ODDS_ACTION/chromedriver', options=chromeOptions)

wbe.get("http://m.diretta.it/?d=0&s=1")
sleep(2)
print(wbe.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="score-data"]/a'))
```

if I start this program in VS it works, but in pythonanywhere it makes this error:

```
/home/Picen22/ODDS_ACTION/prova.py:8: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  wbe = webdriver.Chrome('/home/Picen22/ODDS_ACTION/chromedriver', options=chromeOptions)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/Picen22/ODDS_ACTION/chromedriver'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Picen22/ODDS_ACTION/prova.py", line 8, in <module>
    wbe = webdriver.Chrome('/home/Picen22/ODDS_ACTION/chromedriver', options=chromeOptions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ho
me
```

Comment: Have you tried to setup chrome like in the example on https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium and use chromedriver the pre-installed on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: yes, I tried but it returns an empty string

Comment: If you're using a free account on PA, you have a restricted internet access.